# SmartGit Error in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I installed Smartgit on my Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. But when I wan to start the application it gives me the error described in te image below.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the required Java RE version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: https://www.maketecheasier.com/6-useful-graphical-git-client-for-linux/

Install the OpenJDK instead of the Oracle JRE, you will find that SmartGit won’t run at all. Here’s the fix:

1. Download SmartGit.
2. Extract the tar file to your home folder.
3. Open a file manager and navigate to the bin folder inside the `smartgit` directory. Open the `smartgit.sh` file with a text editor.

Change the line

```
#SMARTGIT_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java
```

to

```
SMARTGIT_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/jre
```

At the last line of code, change the line:

```
$_JAVA_EXEC $_VM_PROPERTIES -Xmx${MAXIMUM_HEAP_SIZE} -Dsmartgit.vm-xmx=${MAXIMUM_HEAP_SIZE} -jar "$SMARTGIT_HOME/lib/smartgit.jar" "$@"
```

to

```
$_JAVA_EXEC $_VM_PROPERTIES -Xmx${MAXIMUM_HEAP_SIZE} -Dsmartgit.checkIncompatibleJava=false -Dsmartgit.vm-xmx=${MAXIMUM_HEAP_SIZE} -jar "$SMARTGIT_HOME/lib/smartgit.jar" "$@"
```

Save the file and close it.

4. Lastly, click the `smartgit.sh` file and select Run when prompted.

SmartGit is free for non-commercial use.